# Are Char type to a UInt16 type in .NET implemented the same under the hood?

Tags: c#, .net, char, type-conversion

Are the types implemented the exact same? This seems weird from a "type-safe" perspective. What's really going on here?

I came across this scenario when in my code I was able to do what's shown with the "b" variable. So playing around with the different types I kind of realize what's happening, but am curious how this is happening under the hood.

```cs
Char a2 = '0';
UInt16 a = a2;
// Int16 a = '2'; // Compile time error
Int32 b = '1';
Int64 c = '2';
```

Comment: Im sure you looked at this before asking the question https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/char, would have saved you time, and answerd every part of your question (without it being weird)

Comment: Int16 != ushort because there is one bit less available than UInt16 = ushort. So you can't convert a char (unsigned 16bit) to a signed Int16. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations

Comment: @TheGeneral It's documented but it doesn't really explain *why* there isn't an implicit cast to UInt16

Comment: @TheGeneral Apparently I didn't know how to get to what I was looking for, but you sound like a nice guy! :)

Comment: @TheGeneral I don't think *"because chars can't be negative"* is a reason, though, since `int` and `long` can be negative and there's an implicit conversion.

Comment: I guess my real question is _why_ does C# allow this? To me it seems ugly from a type safety perspective.

Comment: An implicit conversion from `char` to `short` is most likely not supported because if you converted the character `'耀'` to a `short`, the resulting number is `-32768` (due to overflow, since the `int` value of that character is `32768`, but `short.MaxValue == 32767`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not defined in terms of each other, but *conversions* from one to the other *are* defined. See [MSDN: C# Type Conversions Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit-numeric-conversions-table)

An implicit type conversion is defined from the `char` data type to:

- **ushort**  (alias of UInt16)
- int
- uint
- long
- ulong
- float
- double
- decimal

No implicit type conversation to `short` is defined, because such a conversion would result in a loss of precision.  A `char` is defined in C# as "Unicode 16-bit character".  Using a bit to indicate the sign would result in a possible loss of precision.

See also Eric Lippert's blog post, [Why does char convert implicitly to ushort by not vice versa](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/10/01/why-does-char-convert-implicitly-to-ushort-but-not-vice-versa/)

Comment: Choosing as the correct answer because my question was initiated (in hindsight) by a lack of understanding of implicit type conversion. Numerical type conversions made sense to me, but the character to an integer seemed backwards. 

Your answer led me down the right path to clear my understanding of implicit and explicit type-conversion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

UInt16 = ushort = char = 0..65535 = 2 bytes unsigned = 16bits

So you can put a char in a UInt16 that is a ushort.

Int16 = short != char = -32768..32767 = 2 bytes signed = 15bits + 1sign

So without using a valid cast or a conversion you can't put a char in an Int16 because there is not enough binary space to put 16bits in 15bits.

It is like if you try to put 1 liter of water in a cup of tea : you get an overflow.

The default behavior in C# is to not throw an eception when overflowing.

To have it there is the keyword `checked`.

Here the compiler does not let you to assign a char to Int16 because he know explicitly what you try to do and refuse to do that.

[Learn the basics about C# data types' variables](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/learn-the-basics-about-c-data-types-variables/)

[Unsigned and signed](http://lekhrajkullu.blogspot.com/p/signed-char-one-byte-in-case-of-signed.html)

[Shifting Behavior for Signed Integers](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html#ID36)

[A Tutorial on Data Representation](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/DataRepresentation.html)

[Integer Overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

[Binary Overflow](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-2/binary-overflow/)

Comment: Well actually you can. Both are 2 bytes, there is no loss of information: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YLajOE

Comment: @KevinGosse but isn't that due to overflow? Because `(int)char.MaxValue == 65535` and `short.MaxValue == 32767`

Comment: @RufusL But `short.MinValue == -32768` and `ushort.MinValue == 0`. Both datatypes have the same number of possible values, therefore cast is possible without loss of information. I think the reason the implicit cast is forbidden is because, if you have char in the `32767-65535` range and you cast it to short and ushort, the short and ushort won't be equal (even though you'll get the same value if you cast back to char). I guess that's what makes the cast dangerous

Comment: The point on `checked` is fair. Indeed that's a good reason to make the cast explicit

Comment: @KevinGosse True, but you do lose the true `int` value once you go over `short.MaxValue`. The code sample works because characters with a value greater than `32767` overflow to the negative range, so you'll have a different value for `(int) '耀'` and `(short) '耀'`. But it's correct that there will be no two characters with the same `short` value! The answer should better define what "overflow" means, and modify the line that says "there is not enough place". There *is* enough room, but half the values won't match their `int` value, and require some additional calculations to be meaningful.